# invoke Java Servlet doGet method from JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, servlets, http-get

I want to ask which code I need to write in order to invoke a doGet() in a Java Servlet. Right now the code I had written is:

```
function(){
            var sURL = getUniqueSid("http://localhost:8080/Test/Sample?F=" + f + "&FB=" + fb);
            var ret = xmlSyncHttpReq(sURL);
            if (ret){
                var params = new GG_ContainerParams("General");
                var xTarget = params.dataSource;
                var xElms = ret.selectNodes("Param");
                for (var i=0;i<xElms.length;i++){
                    var x = xElms(i).cloneNode(true);
                    var chk = xTarget.selectSingleNode("Param[@Name = \"" + x.getAttribute("Name") + "\"]");
                    if (chk)xTarget.replaceChild(x,chk);
                    else xTarget.appendChild(x);
                    params.redraw();
                }
            }

function xmlSyncHttpReq(sURL,xmlSend,doThrow){
try{
    var xmlhttp = new  XMLHttpRequest();//ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    sURL = getUniqueSid(sURL);
    xmlhttp.Open("GET", sURL, false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    if (typeof(xmlSend) == "object" && xmlSend != null)xmlSend = xmlSend.xml;
    xmlhttp.Send(xmlSend);  
    if(xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement){
        if (checkErrors(xmlhttp.responseXML))return false;
        else return  xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
    }
    xmlhttp = null;
    return false;
}catch(e){
    if (doThrow)throw e;
    else alert(e.description);
    return false;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Tal Tchernihovski.

Comment: What happens when you run this code ?

Comment: It appears that nothing happned, before the javascript code triggered a ASPX code, but my servlet and the ASPX page has the same response so I don't know why the ASPX page but the servlet doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the JavaScript console in the browser. You should have seen the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object `#<XMLHttpRequest>` has no method `'Open'`

JavaScript follows the Java naming conventions, not C# naming conventions. Methods start with lowercase. You need to use `open()` and `send()` instead of `Open()` and `Send()`.

#### See also:

- [`XMLHttpRequest` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest)